# JS - Grouping array of objects with similar property value but different name

Tags: javascript

I have this array of `message` objects and I wanted to group them that have similar `from - to` value or vice versa.

```
const msgs = [
  { id: '1', from: 'mimi', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-50-249' }, //GROUP THIS
  { id: '5', from: 'gudo', to: 'mimi', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-46-462' }, //

  { id: '2', from: 'john', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-50-249' }, //GROUP THIS
  { id: '3', from: 'gudo', to: 'john', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-46-462' }, //

  { id: '7', from: 'dave', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' }, //GROUP THIS
]
```

This is my take to this, but there's still a problem, I have no clue how to append the obj that has no pair which is the object that has `from` property value of `dave`

```js
let msg = [
  { id: '2', from: 'mimi', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01'},
  { id: '3', from: 'gudo', to: 'mimi', createdAt: '2021-01-02' },
  { id: '5', from: 'gudo', to: 'john', createdAt: '2021-01-03' },
  { id: '4', from: 'john', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' },
  { id: '7', from: 'dave', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' },
]

const sent = msg.filter(i => i.from === 'gudo');
const received = msg.filter(i => i.to === 'gudo');

const res = [];

for (let i = 0; i < sent.length; i++) {
   const curMine = sent[i];
   const pair = [];

   for (let j = 0; j < received.length; j++) {
      const curFrom = received[j];
      
      if(curMine.to === curFrom.from) {
        pair.push(curMine);
        pair.push(curFrom);
      } 
   }
   
   res.push(pair);
}

console.log(res)
```

Expected output:

```
[
  [
    { id: '2', from: 'mimi', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01'},
    { id: '3', from: 'gudo', to: 'mimi', createdAt: '2021-01-02' },
  ],
  [
    { id: '5', from: 'gudo', to: 'john', createdAt: '2021-01-03' },
    { id: '4', from: 'john', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' },
  ],
  [
    { id: '7', from: 'dave', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' }, // How to include this?
  ]
]
]
```

If you could help me or give an idea of a better way of doing this, I would be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you can come up with a way to uniquely identify a single key from a given combination of two participants (regardless of `from` or `to`), grouping into an object indexed by that key should be pretty easy.

I'd sort an array of the two properties alphabetically (and get, eg, `['gudo', 'mimi']`), then pick a character that won't appear in the `from` or `to` properties, then join by that character (eg `gudo#mimi`). That can serve as the key. Then you just need to iterate over the array, and figure out the key for each item:

```js
const msgs = [
  { id: '1', from: 'mimi', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-50-249' }, //GROUP THIS
  { id: '5', from: 'gudo', to: 'mimi', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-46-462' }, //

  { id: '2', from: 'john', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-50-249' }, //GROUP THIS
  { id: '3', from: 'gudo', to: 'john', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-46-462' }, //

  { id: '8', from: 'gudo', to: 'dave', createdAt: '2021-01-01:T-46-462' }, //GROUP THIS
]

const getKey = ({ from, to }) => [to, from]
  .sort((a, b) => a.localeCompare(b))
  .join('#');
const msgsByKey = {};
for (const msg of msgs) {
  const key = getKey(msg);
  if (!msgsByKey[key]) {
    msgsByKey[key] = [];
  }
  msgsByKey[key].push(msg);
}
console.log(Object.values(msgsByKey));
```

Answer (score 1):

Basically you have to push the unprocessed entries to the pair list.

Below is a different approach.

```
let msg = [
  { id: '2', from: 'mimi', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-01'},
  { id: '3', from: 'gudo', to: 'mimi', createdAt: '2021-01-02' },
  { id: '5', from: 'gudo', to: 'john', createdAt: '2021-01-03' },
  { id: '4', from: 'john', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' },
  { id: '7', from: 'dave', to: 'gudo', createdAt: '2021-01-05' },
]

let p = [];
let processed = [];
msg.forEach(function(m) {
  if( processed.indexOf(m.id) >= 0 ) {
    return;
  }
  let filter = msg.filter(function(_m) {
    return m.from === _m.to && m.to === _m.from;
  });
  if( filter && filter.length) {
    p.push([m, filter[0]]);
    processed.push(m.id);
    processed.push(filter[0].id);
  } else {
    p.push(m);
    processed.push(m.id);
  }
});

console.error(p);
```

Comment: Really helpful! Thanks for the idea!